# Append values to dictionary in for loop, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am a bit lousy with dictionary elements and have a query on appending key,value pairs in dict in a loop.
dict.update() overwrites the last value in the dict.

Sample input:

names object is the sample input with name and text will come from different object

```
names = [    'name23.pdf','thisisnew.docx','journey times.docx','Sheet 2018_19.pdf', 'Essay.pdf' ]
```

Expected Output:

```
{'name': 'name23.pdf', 'text': 'text1'}
{'name': 'thisisnew.docx', 'text': 'To be filled'}
{'name': 'journey times.docx', 'text': 'To be filled'}
{'name': 'Sheet 2018_19.pdf', 'text': 'To be filled'}
{'name': 'Essay.pdf', 'text': 'To be filled'}


final_dict = {}
for name in names:
    name = {'name': name,'text' : 'To be filled'}
    final_dict.update(name)
    print(final_dict)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Could you share an expected output?

Comment: Are you aware that a dictionary has only one value per key? Did you intend to make that value a list, and append to it?

Comment: The recent edit has not really cleared up what you intend to do. The code shown already seems to produce the excepted output.

Comment: Append *to what*? You can only append to a list, not a dict. Please [edit] your question to include the expected output as a single Python literal.

Comment: You have to explain how you think a dict works, because I don't think you really understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
names = ['name23.pdf', 'thisisnew.docx', 'journey times.docx', 'Sheet 2018_19.pdf', 'Essay.pdf']
print([{"name": n, "text": "To be filled"} for n in names])
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'name23.pdf', 'text': 'To be filled'}, {'name': 'thisisnew.docx', 'text': 'To be filled'}, {'name': 'journey times.docx', 'text': 'To be filled'}, {'name': 'Sheet 2018_19.pdf', 'text': 'To be filled'}, {'name': 'Essay.pdf', 'text': 'To be filled'}]
```

If you want a `for loop` then you can do this:

```
names = ['name23.pdf', 'thisisnew.docx', 'journey times.docx', 'Sheet 2018_19.pdf', 'Essay.pdf']

output = []
for name in names:
    output.append({'name': name, 'text': 'To be filled'})

print(output)
```

The output is going to be the same as above.

However, using your approach will produce only `one` dictionary with the value of `name` matching the last element from the list. Why? Because keys in a dictionary have to be unique and each key can have only one value.

```
names = ['name23.pdf', 'thisisnew.docx', 'journey times.docx', 'Sheet 2018_19.pdf', 'Essay.pdf']

final_dict = {}
for name in names:
    final_dict.update({'name': name, 'text': 'To be filled'})
    print(final_dict)

print(f"Final result: {final_dict}")
```

Result:

```
{'name': 'name23.pdf', 'text': 'To be filled'}
{'name': 'thisisnew.docx', 'text': 'To be filled'}
{'name': 'journey times.docx', 'text': 'To be filled'}
{'name': 'Sheet 2018_19.pdf', 'text': 'To be filled'}
{'name': 'Essay.pdf', 'text': 'To be filled'}

Final result: {'name': 'Essay.pdf', 'text': 'To be filled'}
```

Comment: I want to create an dict object inside for loop with this output